# Is there a function that copies all instances of a character into same indices in another string?

Tags: c, string, c-standard-library

Essentially what I'm looking for is a standard function that does something like this

```
void transcpy(char *target, const char *src, const char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(target)+1; i++)
        if (src[i] == c) target[i] = c;
}
```

this particular example assumes that `target` and `src` are the same length, but that's not a necessary precondition for what I'm looking for. Although `c` is assumed to appear in `src`.

e. g. `transcpy(word, "word", 'r");` where word is `"____"` would mutate word to be `"__r_"`

this might just be specific to implementing a hangman game, but it seems like a useful enough function that it might have a standard implementation

Comment: No, there's no such standard function. You just have to modify your function to handle the case that both `src` and `target` are not of the same length, null pointer(s), etc.

Comment: I do not know any such function in standard c; In C++, however, lambda functions would offer some more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are a function in standard library that do that, I will implement this as:

```
char *replace_by_c(char *dest, const char *src, size_t size, char c) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (src[i] == c) {
      dest[i] = c;
    }
  }
  return dest;
}
```

In C, it's common to let the user of a function handle the correct size.

```
char str_one[42];
char str_two[84];

size_t min = MIN(sizeof str_one, sizeof str_two);
replace_by_c(str_one, str_two, min, 'c');
```

This let a function to be use in a lot of situations, for example this function can work without `NUL` terminate and can handle a character `NUL` as `c`.

```
replace_by_c(dest, src, 42, '\0');
```

Comment: this does not handle the case where the source and destination arrays are of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

here is one possible implementation, which does handle when the two strings are not the same length

```
char *transcpy(char *dest, const char *src, char c)
{
    size_t shortest = strlen(dest);

    if( strlen( dest ) > strlen(src ) )
        shortest = strlen( src );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < shortest; i++)
    {
        if( c == src[i])
        {
            dest[i] = c;
        }
    }

    return dest;
} // end function: transcpy
```